# Issues with select dropdown Flat-UI Design Framework (based on twitter bootstrap 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

The problem - you don't get flat UI working in Rails. The value of attribute doesn't get updated once you save your object.

For example:

You are trying to update attribute "language_id" in your table, using the following statement:

```
<%= f.select(:language_id, Language.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}) %>
```

If you wish to use Flat-UI (based on twitter bootstrap) you would have to do the following:

```
<%= f.select(:language_id, Language.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {  }, { :class => "selectpicker", :name => "large"}) %>
```

You have to add class selectpicker (from bootstrap) and add name = large (or any other value taken from flat UI's application.js:

```
$("select[name='huge']").selectpicker({style: 'btn-hg btn-primary', menuStyle: 'dropdown-inverse'});
$("select[name='large']").selectpicker({style: 'btn-lg btn-default'});
$("select[name='info']").selectpicker({style: 'btn-info'});
$("select[name='small']").selectpicker({style: 'btn-sm btn-warning'});
```

The issue now is that it won't be working ! It may looks nicely designed but the value is not updating. The reason being is that rails requires the name attribute - which is now overwritten by the name of button-style you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to rename button styles in the application.js of flat-ui. For exmaple:

```
$("select[nameui='huge']").selectpicker({style: 'btn-hg btn-primary', menuStyle: 'dropdown-inverse'});
$("select[nameui='large']").selectpicker({style: 'btn-lg btn-default'});
$("select[nameui='info']").selectpicker({style: 'btn-info'});
$("select[nameui='small']").selectpicker({style: 'btn-sm btn-warning'});
```

and introduce the new tag in your form:

```
<%= f.select(:language_id, Language.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {  }, { :class => "selectpicker", :nameui => "large"}) %>
```

And all should be working just fine from here!

(Ps.: make usre you have bootstrap-select.js added to your asset-pipeline!)